# heroku error : Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError:

Tags: python, machine-learning, heroku, web-applications, web-deployment

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SGn9.png)

i am trying to deploy django web app in heroku. after giving this command git push heroku master I am getting this error. please help me to understand and solve this error

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem was with the requirements.txt file also with the size of the slug.

What I did is.

1. As @Alexis Wong said I was using tensorflow 2. it took a lot of space so changed it to tensorflow 1.14
2. I have removed unwanted packages from the requirements file

problem solved...

Answer (score 0):

It says:

```
Processing /C:/ci/absl-py_1615411229697/work
```

That's not a file path that exists on a Linux system.

Share the content of your `requirements.txt` and/or `Pipfile`. You probably have a locally defined path there which only exists on your system.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Sorry, I did not see the image, usually thats a library that does not work on the heroku environment, maybe due to a newer version or an older one, you can take a look at your requeriments.txt and try to locate that library,and refactor i, is pretty painful but try changing versions and optimizing the imports, keep it simple and minimal to get the answer.

Your questions lacks on description but, I guess that your problem is due to the compile slug size, you should use minimum libraries to reduce the size of the app, if you are using django you must serve images and resources from another microservice, If you are using Tensorflow 2 you must change that version to an older one like 1.14 because it is light, works with your current stack and maybe solve that issue, if it does not work you must consider changing the TF serving to JS as is the newest way to do that.

Comment: Slug size is the problem. As you said if I change tensorflow to older version it would work. I hope

Comment: I hope you can deploy your app! Please share more if you need more help